# Storing state between decorators in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching, functional-programming, python-decorators

I'll start by saying, I have a suspicion this is a solution that could be solved with a functional programming approach, but I don't know nearly enough of the concepts (but have been trying).

I've based my current solution on:

- https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/python-decorators/
- http://www.brianholdefehr.com/decorators-and-functional-python
- https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/blob/master/click/decorators.py

In the interest of learning (that's all this is!) how to build decorators, I decided to make a simple cache decorator.

But I get stuck in a loop where, I try to encapsulate the function I'm wrapping in a class, but every time I call the function I've wrapped, I call __call__ in wrapping class and so on ad infinitum.

I think I could have a nest of closures between the chain decorators, but I don't know how to collect all my variables in one scope.

I appreciate I could put all my arguments in a single decorator call, but my intention here is to learn how to chain decorators and store state between them.

Can anyone suggest a way (or ammend my way) to store state between chained decorators?

My intended design was:

```py
# main.py
import http.client
from cache import cache

@cache.keys('domain', 'url')
@cache.lifetime(3600)
def make_http_request(domain,url='/'):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(domain)
    conn.request("GET",url)
    return conn.getresponse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_http_request('http://example.com/'))
```

with cache.py looking like

```py
import hashlib
import os
import inspect

__author__ = 'drews'

def expand(path):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(path))

class CacheManager():
    """Decorator to take the result and store it in a a file. If the result is needed again, then the file result is returned"""

    def __init__(self, function, function_arg_name):
        self.lifetime = 3600
        self.cache_keys = None
        self.cache_path = '~/.decorator_cache/'

        self.f = function
        self.arg_names = function_arg_name

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 0:
            arg_names = self.arg_names
            if 'self' in arg_names:
                arg_names.remove('self')
            key_args = dict(zip(arg_names, args))
            key_args.update(kwargs)
        else:
            key_args = kwargs
        self._initialise(cache_path=expand(self.cache_path))
        key = self._build_key(key_args)
        if self.key_exists(key):
            result = self.get_key(key)
        else:
            result = self.f()
            self.set_key(key, result)
        return result

    def _build_key(self, key_elements):
        m = hashlib.md5()
        for key in self.cache_keys:
            m.update(key_elements[key].encode('utf-8'))
        return m.hexdigest()

    def _initialise(self, cache_path):
        def initialise_path(path):
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                (head, tail) = os.path.split(path)
                if not os.path.isdir(head):
                    initialise_path(head)
                os.mkdir(path)

        initialise_path(cache_path)

    def key_exists(self, key):
        path = os.path.join(expand(self.cache_path), key)
        return os.path.exists(path)


class CacheDefinitionDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.d_args = args


class CacheKeyDefinitionDecorator(CacheDefinitionDecorator):
    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(func, CacheManager):
            func = CacheManager(func,inspect.getargspec(func)[0])
        func.cache_keys = self.d_args
        return func


class CacheLifetimeDefintionDecorator(CacheDefinitionDecorator):
    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(func, CacheManager):
            func = CacheManager(func,inspect.getargspec(func)[0])
        func.lifetime = self.d_args[0]
        return func

class CacheStruct(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for item in kwargs:
            setattr(self, item, kwargs[item])


cache = CacheStruct(
    keys=CacheKeyDefinitionDecorator,
    lifetime=CacheLifetimeDefintionDecorator
)
```

Comment: Can you post the exception you're seeing and the code that produces it?

Comment: ... and why not just do: `@cache(lifetime=3600, keys=[('domain', 'url')])`?